# Require non-custom fields?

Tags: custom-fields

Question:  How do I require the first and last names on Individuals?

I need to require some global fields in the CiviCRM backend GUI.  Specifically, I need to require the First and Last name for individuals on the standard individual create/edit backend webforms.

I thought there was an admin page to set this, but can't find it right now and I suspect other people will be interested in the answer too.

Answer (score 5):

You can make any fields "required" when they are part of a profile.

Admninister > Customize data and screens > Profiles > Fields > Edit

Answer (score 3):

You can do that developing a custom extension. As far as I know, there is no way to configure mandatory fields from the UI.

How to create an extension [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension) or you can use use [civix](https://github.com/totten/civix/).
In your extension, in the main extension's .php file, you can use civicrm hooks, in this case:

```
hook_civicrm_validateForm( $formName, &$fields, &$files, &$form, &$errors )
```

For your example, let's say I create my extension as **org.civicrm.myextension**.
In myextension.php add this for making First Name mandatory:

```
function myextension_civicrm_validateForm( $formName, &$fields, &$files, &$form, &$errors ){
    if ( $formName == 'CRM_Contact_Form_Contact' ) {
       // ensure that first name is not empty
       $first_name = CRM_Utils_Array::value( 'first_name', $fields );
       if ( empty($first_name) ) {
          $errors['first_name'] = ts( 'First Name is a required field' );
       }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be simpler and easier to add this behavior via jQuery / javascript and include it in an extra custom template file.

https://civicrm.org/blogs/dave-greenberg/now-its-easier-add-custom-behaviors-templates